# How to use Hibernate Validator Annotations with Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have searched the internet for days now with no luck of finding anything relevant or up to date on this topic. I'm trying to do some simple form validation using annotations using Hibernate Validator 5.4.1 Final and Validation-api 1.1.0 Final. Without even adding any annotations to my code I get the error shown below from just adding these two jars to my lib folder. Please please please any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: post the code of your class where you put the anotations for get help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "Hibernate Validator" dependency or "validator-api"? 
validator-api dont have implementation for validation.
You should use [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator)

Comment: I'm not using dependencies I've downloaded the jar file and added it to the library. I'm very new to spring mvc and even newer to hibernate. tutorials i've seen explain to use hibernate-validator jar and validation-api jar. When i add both those jars is when i get the error.

Comment: I think this error happen cuz of incompatable jar's. I advice u to use dependecny management tools like maven or gralde. It's not hard to learn for basic usage but it will help you to add/remove/edit dependencies a lot.
If there are dependency that depends on other jar's, then dependency management tool will add them automatically.
All that you need its to install maven https://maven.apache.org/
And create pom.xml that will describe ur dependencies https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: I would rather import the jars manually than use maven do you not know why i get this error ? which jars do you think are not compatible?

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but by using maven it doesn't actually store the dependencies within my project does it ? it just creates a reference to them ? if this is the case and that dependency was to be removed, would my application stop working ?

Comment: Yes. Maven downloads dependencies in his own folder. How problem about its deployment solved? 1) WAR archive - its contains your jar content, all your libraries(dependencies), resources and web resources. 2) You can use copy-dependencies goal for maven, to force it to put all your dependencies to destinated location [more info about copy-dependencies goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)

Comment: so there's no solution to my problem without using maven ?